# Advice needed with Android ssh app

Tags: android, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to make a small application in android to run commands over ssh with jsch library. No where is the problem I have but when I run the app I get a window:

Unfortunately, application has stopped.

This is my code:

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxxxxxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivty:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     


    TextView tvBd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtNombre);    

    ConexionSSH conect = new ConexionSSH();
    String prueba = "pepe";     

    try {
        prueba = conect.conect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tvBd.setText("LS: "+prueba);
```

Conection class:

```
String user = "xxxxx";
String host = "xxxxx";  
int port = 22;
String pass = "xxxxx";

public String conectar() throws Exception {     

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
    session.setPassword(pass);

    // Avoid asking for key confirmation
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(prop);

    session.connect();

    // SSH Channel
    ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) 
                    session.openChannel("exec");      
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

    // Execute command
    channelssh.setCommand("ls");
    channelssh.connect();        
    channelssh.disconnect();

    return baos.toString();
}
```

Logcat:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.sarai55.ConexionSSH
at com.example.sarai55.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat output which will contain details of the error that is occurring. Without this no-one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest version of the SSHJ library from https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/downloads
Extract the zip file and copy the “sshj-0.8.1.jar” into the libs directory of your android project.
Include the dependencies of the SSHJ library also in the build path.
SLF4J - logging library. (slf4j-api-1.6.99.jar, slf4j-simple-1.6.99.jar)
Bounty Castle – Security library. (bcpkix-jdk15on-147.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar)
JZlib – Compression library. ()
Include the above mentioned jar files also into the lib folder of the Android project.

Comment: I added all the. Jar to the libs folder and included the libraries dependencies also in the build path but still stopping the application with the window message: Unfortunately, application has stopped.

Thanks anyway

Comment: just go to this link http://rgksugan.in/2012/09/using-ssh-from-android/       hope this will help you ....

Comment: This is very useful but I get error TAG::

                try {
   ssh.connect(host, port);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      ---------> Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage(), e);
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: @NipunGogia the link you have provided is dead.